# Как осуществить замену всех прописных букв на строчные?

Tags: c#, текст

У меня есть код для построчного считывания текстового файла, но не знаю как изменить регистр в в нем.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fileIn = new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FileStream fileOut = new FileStream("newText.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            int i;

            while ((i = fileIn.ReadByte())!=-1)
            {
                //запись очередного файла в поток, связанный с файлом fIleOut
                fileOut.WriteByte((byte)i); 
            } 
            fileIn.Close();
            fileOut.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(EX.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: У Вас код не для построчного, а для побайтового считывания файла. Со всякими там UTF будет ай-яй-яй.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем усложнять себе жизнь?

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText("text.txt");
        var lowerText = text.ToLower();
        File.WriteAllText("newText.txt", lowerText);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Почитать:

- [`File.ReadAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`String.ToLower()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`File.WriteAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А еще можно   `File.ReadAllText("newText.txt", File.ReadAllText("text.txt").ToLower());`

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик я за читабельный код, который легко дебажить.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const string fileIn = @"C:\users\admin\documents\file_in.txt";
    const string fileOut = @"C:\users\admin\documents\file_out.txt";

    try
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(fileIn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None), Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"), false))
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileOut, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None), Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251")))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line.ToLower());
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```